# Create dummy and categorical variables from specific word(s) in text column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, variables, text

I am trying to generate dummy and categorical variables from a text column in a dataframe, using Python. Imagine a text column 'Cars_notes' in a dataframe named 'Cars_listing':

```
- "This Audi has ABS braking, leather interior and bucket seats..."
- "The Ford F150 is one tough pickup truck, with 4x4, new suspension and club cab..."
- "Our Nissan Sentra comes with ABS brakes, Bluetooth-enabled radio..."
- "This Toyota Corolla is a gem, with new tires, low miles, a few scratches..."
- "The Renault Le Car has been sitting in the garage, a little rust..."
- "The Kia Sorento for sale has a CD player, new tires..."
- "Red Dodge Viper convertible for sale, ceramic brakes, low miles..."
```

How to make new variables:

```
- car_type: American [Ford] (1), European [Audi, Renault] (2), Asian [Toyota, Kia] (3)
- ABS_brakes: description includes 'ABS brak' (1), or not (0)
- imperfection: description includes 'rust' or 'scratches' (1) or not (0)
- sporty: description includes 'convertible' (1) or not (0)
```

I have started by trying re.search() (not re.match()), such as:

```
sporty = re.search("convertible",'Cars_notes')
```

I am just starting to learn Python text manipulation and NLP. I have searched for information here as well as other sources (Data Camp, Udemy, Google searching) but I have not yet found something to explain how to manipulate text to create such categorical or dummy variables. Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on this.

Since you're dealing with text, [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) should be plenty (no need to use `re.search`.

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) are useful when it comes to assigning new variables based on conditions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Cars_listing = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cars_notes': 
    ['"This Audi has ABS braking, leather interior and bucket seats..."',
    '"The Ford F150 is one tough pickup truck, with 4x4, new suspension and club cab..."',
    '"Our Nissan Sentra comes with ABS brakes, Bluetooth-enabled radio..."',
    '"This Toyota Corolla is a gem, with new tires, low miles, a few scratches..."',
    '"The Renault Le Car has been sitting in the garage, a little rust..."',
    '"The Kia Sorento for sale has a CD player, new tires..."',
    '"Red Dodge Viper convertible for sale, ceramic brakes, low miles..."']
})


# 1. car_type
Cars_listing['car_type'] = np.select(
    condlist=[ # note you could use the case-insensitive search with `case=False`
        Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('ford', case=False),
        Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('audi|renault', case=False),
        Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('Toyota|Kia')
    ],
    choicelist=[1, 2, 3], # dummy variables
    default=0 # you could set it to `np.nan` etc
)

# 2. ABS_brakes
Cars_listing['ABS_brakes'] = np.where(# where(condition, [x, y])
    Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('ABS brak'), 1, 0)

# 3. imperfection
Cars_listing['imperfection'] = np.where(
    Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('rust|scratches'), 1, 0)

# 4. sporty
Cars_listing['sporty'] = np.where(
    Cars_listing['Cars_notes'].str.contains('convertible'), 1, 0)
```

```py
    Cars_notes              car_type    ABS_brakes  imperfection    sporty
0   """This Audi has ..."   2           1           0               0
1   """The Ford F150 ..."   1           0           0               0
2   """Our Nissan Sen..."   0           1           0               0
3   """This Toyota Co..."   3           0           1               0
4   """The Renault Le..."   2           0           1               0
5   """The Kia Sorent..."   3           0           0               0
6   """Red Dodge Vipe..."   0           0           0               1
```

Comment: Great example! Thank you so much for this!